# evernote.edam.userstore.UserStore.Client: HTTP Status 400

Tags: python-3.x, api, evernote

**My python app (evernote-sdk-python3) worked fine until June, 3rd**. Suddenly it breaks e.g. when I call "**client.get_user_store()**" or "**client.get_note_store()**". All calls to "**evernote.edam.userstore.UserStore.Client**" respond with **HTTP status 400** (*The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)*). I tried it in a sandbox and on the production server and I renewed the auth token. Nothing helped. Something on evernote's side must have changed. My app worked perfectly before.

Answer (score 0):

the Evernote python3 SDK just got a patch, please grab the latest and try again